# How to handle HTTP and WebSocket connections on the same port in a Deno server?

Tags: http, websocket, port, deno

I have decided to use Deno for developing a very small server that would serve a minimal page to the clients through HTTP and continue to communicate with them through WebSockets.

I haven't managed to find any material online about providing HTTP and WebSocket over a single port with Deno (at least no without using some third party libraries, I haven't yet checked those), so I tried to come up with a solution myself, but have been running into a weird issue.

Here's my code so far:

```
// Accept TCP connections over port 8080
for await (const connection of Deno.listen({ port: 8080 })) {
  // Process all the arriving requests
  for await (const requestEvent of Deno.serveHttp(connection)) {
    // Check for the presence of an upgrade header
    if (requestEvent.request.headers.get('upgrade') === 'websocket') {
      // Provide a WebSocket connection
      const { socket, response } = Deno.upgradeWebSocket(requestEvent.request)
      socket.addEventListener('message', e => { console.log(e.data) })
      requestEvent.respondWith(response)
    } else {
      // Otherwise just respond normally
      requestEvent.respondWith(new Response('Hello!'))
    }
  }
}
```

The strange behavior I get when running this is that I can initially connect through either of the protocols, but as soon as I connect with a plain HTTP client, I can no longer create new WebSocket connections. The other way around works perfectly fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have managed to figure this one out while minimizing my reproducible example for presentation here, but I thought that I'd still post it, since it could be a useful resource for others as well.

So, the issue with my code is that I have made almost everything synchronous apart from the handling of the WebSocket messages. This causes the loop to be stuck serving a single HTTP connection, and prevents it from dealing with other connections and their requests. Sure enough if I try to connect from another device, that doesn't work either.

To fix it, I just needed to make one minor adjustment, giving each connection its own event handler loop by wrapping that part in an *Immediately Invoked Async Arrow Function*:

```
// Accept TCP connections over port 8080
for await (const connection of Deno.listen({ port: 8080 })) {
  // Split off a dedicated asynchronous loop
  (async () => {
    // Process all the arriving requests
    for await (const requestEvent of Deno.serveHttp(connection)) {
      // Check for the presence of an upgrade header
      if (requestEvent.request.headers.get('upgrade') === 'websocket') {
        // Provide a WebSocket connection
        const { socket, response } = Deno.upgradeWebSocket(requestEvent.request)
        socket.addEventListener('message', e => { console.log(e.data) })
        requestEvent.respondWith(response)
      } else {
        // Otherwise just respond normally
        requestEvent.respondWith(new Response('Hello!'))
      }
    }
  })()
}
```

---

ps.: Maybe using `.accept().then(<connection handling code here>)` on the [Listener](https://deno.land/api@v1.35.0?s=Deno.Listener#method_accept_0) in a loop would be more readable to some people, I guess that's a little subjective.